# Why is my D code for finding prime numbers much faster than my C++ code?

Tags: c++, d

I coded two small projects in C++ and D(lang) respectively to calculate a given number of prime numbers. The code is very similar in both projects. However, my D code runs MUCH faster than my C++ code, even though C++ is said to be faster. I use dmd and dub for compiling D code and clang (LLVM 11.0) with Visual C++ for compiling my C++ code. I use Visual Studio Code for actually developing and compiled my C++ program from the command line, though with -O3. I am sorry if some variable names don't match up, I quickly translated my code from German. Below is my code:

#### C++ implementation:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

#include "isqrt.hpp"

bool prime(int number)
{
    for(unsigned i = 2; i < isqrt(number)+1; i++)
    {
        if (!(number % i))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Prime numbers\n-------------------------\n" << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the amount of prime numbers you want to get calculated: ";
        unsigned amount;
        std::cin >> amount;

        std::vector<unsigned> prime_numbers = {2,3,5};
        unsigned start = 6;
        bool p;
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point before = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        while(prime_numbers.size() < amount)
        {
            p = prime(start);
            if(p)
            {
                prime_numbers.push_back(start);
            }
            start++;
        }
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point after = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        //std::cout << prime_numbers << std::endl;
        std::chrono::system_clock::duration diff = after - before;
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(diff).count() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Why has thou forsaken me?" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

isqrt.hpp:

```
#ifndef ISQRT_HPP
#define ISQRT_HPP

unsigned isqrt(unsigned number);

#endif
```

isqrt.cpp:

```
#include "isqrt.hpp"

unsigned isqrt(unsigned number) {
    if (!number) return 0;

    unsigned left = 1;
    unsigned right = (number >> 1) + 1;
    unsigned res;
    unsigned mid;
 
    while (left <= right) {
        mid = left + ((right-left) >> 1);
        if (mid*mid < number){
            left = mid+1;
            res=mid;
        }
        else {
            right=mid-1;
        }
    }
 
    return res;
}
```

#### D implementation:

main.d:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.datetime.stopwatch;

import isqrt;

/** Whether the number is a prime */
bool prime(int number)
{
    foreach(i; 2 .. iSqrt(number)+1)
    {
        if (!(number % i))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void main()
{
    writeln("Prime numbers\n-------------------------\n");
    auto sw = StopWatch(AutoStart.no);
    int amount;
    while (true)
    {
        sw.reset();
        write("Please enter the amount of prime numbers that are to be calculated: ");
        readf("%d\n",amount);

        int[] prime_numbers = [2,3];
        int start = 5;
        bool p;
        sw.start();
        while(prime_numbers.length < amount)
        {
            p = prime(start);
            if(p)
            {
                primzahlen ~= start;
            }
            start++;
        }
        sw.stop();
        //writefln("%(%s%|, %)\n",prime_numbers);
        writeln(sw.peek.total!"msecs");
    }
}
```

isqrt.d:

```
module isqrt;

/** Int squareroot */

public uint iSqrt(uint number) {
    if (!number) return 0;

    uint left = 1;
    uint right = number >> 1 + 1;
    uint res;
    uint mid;
 
    while (left <= right) {
        mid = left + ((right-left) >> 1);
        if (mid<=number/mid){
            left = mid+1;
            res=mid;
        }
        else {
            right=mid-1;
        }
    }
 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us *exactly* how you build the programs. We need to know all the flags and options used when building. We also need to know how you time the programs.

Comment: For D I just use "dub", which automatically builds with DMD. For C++  I used: "clang -c -Wall -O3 -m64 isqrt.cpp -o isqrt.o" and "clang -c -Wall -O3 -m64 main.cpp -o main.o" and lastly linked with "clang -Wall -O3 -m64 main.o isqrt.o -o main.exe"

Comment: Please also include your inputs, and be more specific than "MUCH faster".

Comment: Your `isqrt`function seems rather slow. I guess the problem is in this function. Moreover, here, `for(unsigned i = 2; i < isqrt(number)+1; i++)`, it might happen that this slow function is called at *each* iteration.

Comment: i dont know D, but your C++ code measusures allocations. Perhaps a small difference but you should do `prime_numbers.reserve(amount)` outside of the timing if you want to compare the computing part

Comment: When I try to calculate 10_000 prime numbers, my D program needs ~31ms while my C++ program needs ~220ms. I measure the time as seen in the code: StopWatch in D and chrono::system_clock in C++

Comment: If you look at the assembly code generated by the C++ code (for example using [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a1rzKrfE4)) you can see that the `isqrt` function will be called *every* iteration of the loop. The same doesn't seem to happen [for the D code](https://godbolt.org/z/d3MovxaqY). So for the C++ code, do the `isqrt(number)+1` before the loop, and store the result in a variable that you use in the loop instead. That should change quite a lot.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, but I see a call in line 62 for the D code. That isn't the case.

Comment: @KarlSchrader Yes, *one* call, *outside* the loop.

Comment: I multiply the speed by about 10 by calculation `int imax = std::sqrt(number)+1;` before the loop

Comment: Sorry, now I get it. Thank yall! But it really should be optimized by the compiler imo.

Comment: @KarlSchrader Optimizing that requires some cross-translation unit information, which most compiler don't use (AFAIK). When compiling `man.cpp`, C++ cannot assume that your `iSqrt` in the other translation unit is a "pure" function without side effects. What if it contained some `std::cout << "hi\n"` inside? In such case the compiler cannot call it only once without breaking the intended semantics of `for`.

Comment: I guess that's why I love D so much.

Comment: Not every question on Stackoverflow needs an accepted answer. This is a simple problem in a very specific code. It's pretty unlikely that someone else has a similar problem and is looking for the solution. Of course you could reformulate the question and make it more generic. A question like "Why is `isqrt(number)` in a for loop not optimized" could be useful.

Comment: note that `dub` doesn't compile with optimizations by default, you need to request that in your config file

Comment: or `dub -b release` does optimizations too

Comment: I'm a fan of D as well (and a fan of Bright, Alexandrescu and Ruppe too!).  The C++ code can only be optimized in the way you are asking if using LTO or WPO, and since you did not provide the compile command I suspect that LTO or WPO was not provided.  But moreso, for performance comparison, the burden to make the two test cases similar-and-fair is on your shoulders, not the compiler's optimizer's shoulders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you slightly change your main.cpp

```
diff main.old.cpp main.cpp
9c9,10
<     for(unsigned i = 2; i < isqrt(number)+1; i++)
---
>     int max = isqrt(number) + 1;
>     for(unsigned i = 2; i < max; i++)
```

And rebuild your C++ code again

```
g++ -O3 -o cppisqrt isqrt.cpp main.cpp
```

You will see that C++ version is only slightly slower then D version compiled with

```
gdc -O3 -o disqrt isqrt.d main.d
```

I wanted to be fair and used the same compiler backend (G++ and GDC both use GCC backend). On my home workstation C++ variant takes ~1140ms (average of 10 samples) for 200000 numbers, while D variant takes ~1090ms (also 10 samples mean).

Both G++ and GDC produce similar code:

GCC 10.2 x86-64 on https://godbolt.org produces

```
isqrt(unsigned int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 0
        jne     .L2
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        shr     eax
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
.L7:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        ja      .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        shr     eax
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        imul    eax, eax
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], eax
        jbe     .L5
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
        jmp     .L7
.L5:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        sub     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
        jmp     .L7
.L4:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
.L3:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

GDC 10.2 x86-64 on https://godbolt.org produces

```
uint example.iSqrt(uint):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 0
        jne     .L2
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        shr     eax, 2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
.L7:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        ja      .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        shr     eax
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        add     eax, edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     edx, 0
        div     DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], eax
        ja      .L5
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
        jmp     .L7
.L5:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        sub     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
        jmp     .L7
.L4:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
.L3:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

PS. D version does not need that `public` specifier in this case.